# Cellular homology produce the same result with either CW-decompositions

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Suppose you have two CW-decompositions for the same space $X$.Show that cellular homology produce the same result with either CW-decompositions.

Could anyone give me a hint about the proof or tell me if it is in Hatcher?

Comment: It is in Hatcher since he proves that cellular homology is isomorphic to singular homology, which depends only of the topology.

Comment: Do you mean that this is true because simplicial homology is isomorphic to cellular homology ?@Balloon

Comment: If so what is the relation between CW complex and simplicial homology?@Balloon

Comment: I am not seeing at all what you saying ... the question is asking to prove that if we have 2 CW-complex structures we have the same result of cellular homology @Balloon

Comment: To answer your first comment: yes, that's exactly that. Perhaps your question requires to find an isomorphism directly from one cellular homology to the other one, but my comment says that you can first find an isomorphism between the first cellular homology and the singular one, then a second isomorphism between the second cellular homology and the singular one, then compose the two to get an isomorphism between the cellular ones.

Comment: @Balloon You should give an official answer.

Comment: What about my second comment above .... what is the relation between CW complex and a simplex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul suggested, I will copy my comment as an answer (since it could be the one of the solutions you are looking for):

It is in Hatcher since he proves that cellular homology is isomorphic to singular homology, which depends only of the topology.

Comment: Could you please interpret you thoughts mathematically ? as I am unable to do this.

Comment: The statement "cellular homology is isomorphic to singular homology" is already mathematical.